# As a system administrator, what Firefox plugin helps you do your job?

Tags: monitoring, firefox

I know that there are several Firefox plugins that are invaluable for development.  What plugins exist that are useful for system administration, monitoring, and the like?  What plugins make your day-to-day job as a system or network administrator easier?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is on the CW border or not.  I'll check in an hour or so to see if there's a balance of comments in either direction on whether this should be CW or not.

Comment: Voting for close... if I could.  "What is your favorite cheese sandwich... as a system administrator."  Honestly.  Can't wait until we get a good group of 3k+ editors.

Comment: yep... community wiki

Comment: @Adam Davis, did you wake up on the wrong side of the bed that day?  Asking "what tool do you use to do your job" is different from asking "what do you eat at your job."  I updated the title to make it more clear, but this is directly related to doing sysadmin tasks.  The answers below directly relate to doing sysadmin tasks. This is not a "how do you decorate your cube" question.

Comment: It took five days for two people to chime in and say, "Yes this should be CW," which doesn't indicate a strong preference.  Still, given two such opinions, I have changed this to be CW.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ShowIP](http://code.google.com/p/firefox-showip/) - allows me to see quickly the IP address of the server where a particular website is hosted.  Assists in managing my many clients websites.

[DNSCache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5914) - quickly disable/re-enable Firefox's builtin DNS Cache, particularly good if your also manipulating the site's DNS at the time

[ScreenGrab](http://www.screengrab.org/) - particularly good at capturing that error and sending to the developers.

Answer (score 15):

[Foxyproxy](http://foxyproxy.mozdev.org/) - I cant stand getting attacked by others when they walk over with their stats and say "Hm this Serverfault.com you wasted 5 minutes of our time on it."

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more.

Comment: this looks more like a tool that would give sysadmins work to do! Maybe give it to all the end users as a ploy to get better funding for network security projects?

Answer (score 9):

Even for IT, I'd have to put FireBug at the top of the list, too much good information in there.and

Answer (score 8):

[Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) this is handy when you have to examine HTTP headers.  This may be necessary if you have virtual hosts in a hosting environment.  We also insert a field in the header to identify web machines in some of our web farms to identify problem hosts.

Answer (score 6):

[Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/), cause who wants to maintain a local only copy of their Firefox bookmarks. [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) will sync your bookmarks across Firefox, IE etc on all your computers. It's fast and stays out of the way.

Comment: Now when will it sync my Chrome bookmarks? :(

Answer (score 4):

[WebMail Notifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4490) - Tracks web email accounts

[Live http headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) - great for trouble shooting websites

[Ghostery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9609) watch the websites that watch you

Answer (score 4):

[Delicious Bookmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3615) to sync my bookmarks across machines.

Comment: Yes! Yes! Yes!  It's like a catch-all of all the useful content I've come across, tagged and sorted.

Answer (score 3):

[LastPass](http://lastpass.com/). So I don't have to remember the loads of accounts I use (and can generate very strong passwords for each of your accounts), both personal and at work.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using amazon ec2; [elasticfox](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=609)

Answer (score 3):

[Nagios Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3607) is pretty nice.

Answer (score 2):

Firebug and YSlow! FTW

However I don't see why a web browser is a crucial tool for sysadmins, curl ? wget ? telnet host 80 ?

Comment: I admin vmware server 2.x. If I don't run a website, I've got to use the 1500 character-long command lines.

Answer (score 2):

[ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115) - so I can get SO refresh automagically while working!

[AdBlockPlus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865) - because so many sites have ads that I don't care about.

Mentioned before, but super +1 for [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) and [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5369) because there's typically some good information that can be gleaned depending on what issue you might get roped in to.

Answer (score 2):

[Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) and the many [scripts available](http://userscripts.org/) for it is all I need.

Answer (score 2):

[Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) with Firefox plugin is much better than Firebug network statistics.

Answer (score 1):

- [Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/)
- [S3Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3247)

Answer (score 1):

[Fireftp](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/) for when you don't want to install an ftp client

Answer (score 1):

In addition to others already mentioned, I find [SQLite Manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

Update Scanner - For every site you have keep tabs on that doesn't have email notifications or rss.

If you ar using google apps:

Active Inbox - GTD for mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't work without [something to give you rhythm](http://www.foxytunes.com/)